# Control+Z in Windows to signal end of input c++?

Tags: c++, windows, input

Is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> just the undo command in Windows?

I'm trying

```
  do cin>>x;
  while(cin);
```

And doing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to signify end of input, but it doesn't work.  What is end of input signal for Windows then?

Answer (score 1):

Console input is also, by default, *line buffered*. You must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.